# MySQL 5.7 Replication

Tags: mysql, server, mariadb

I have 4 masters with same name of the databases but i want to replicate on a different database for every master on one slave. How i can do this?
For example:

- Master1 database: DB_A --------------> Slave database: DB_A_1
- Master2 database: DB_A --------------> Slave database: DB_A_2
- Master3 database: DB_A --------------> Slave database: DB_A_3
- Master4 database: DB_A --------------> Slave database: DB_A_4

Answer (score 0):

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/multi-source-replication/
Use a connection together with `replicate-rewrite-db`